# How to return a node that's the same name as another node but of a specific label? Neo4J

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm working with financial data, and I want to find a name match between a name that's a synonym of a line item, and another node that has the same name as that synonym but is in a separate node unrelated to the synonym graph and has a specified attribute type that needs to be defined.

Here is some data:

```
 CREATE (n:Test1 {name: "x"})-[r:syn_of]->(s:Test2 {name: "y"})
 CREATE (n:Test3 {value: "x"})
```

So Test3 has the same value stored in attribute format as Test1, but the attribute label is different. How can I return the 'x' from the value attribute of Test3, by querying using Test1 and/or Test2? I know this is a strange problem and due to confidentiality reasons I can't specify why I'm doing this but if anyone could be any help this would be paramount. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the given input in your question so I have two possible queries for you to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS. It will check if there is a connection between Test1 and Test2 before returning the value of Test3. Then you can have a condition on your query that says Test3.value = 'x'. Depending on your input value, your query will look like below;

> Given Test1.name ='x' and Test2.name = 'y'

```
 MATCH (n:Test3 {value: 'x'})
 WHERE EXISTS ( (:Test1 {name: "x"})-[:syn_of]->(:Test2 {name: "y"}) )
 RETURN n
```

Using WITH clause, you have a variable nameTest1 and assign this to Test3.value

> Given Test2.name = 'y'

```
MATCH (n:Test1)-[:syn_of]->(:Test2 {name: "y"})
WITH n.name as nameTest1
MATCH (n3:Test3 {value: nameTest1 })
RETURN n3
```